# git svn only use branches without trunk or tags

Tags: git, git-branch, git-svn

I have an SVN repo with a normal trunk/branches/tags layout. For my git I want to ignore the trunk & tags folder. I just want to have the branches as git branches nothing more.

Folders:

```
/trunk (empty)
/tags (full of stuff I want to ignore)
/branches/folder1
/branches/folder2
```

I tried simply cloning the svn using

```
git svn clone [REPO] -stdlayout
```

Unfortunately my client has not commited anything into the trunk so I get the error "refs/remotes/origin/trunk not a valid SHA1"
I read that no commit into the trunk results in that error.

My question is: How can I only use the branches folder1 & folder2 to create a new git with said branches.

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You obviously don't need `--stdlayout` which implies trunk, branches and tags. Instead you could specify explicitly what you would like to be fetched from svn. Most probably something like this would work for you:

```
git svn init http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/email --branches=branches/*
git svn fetch
```

first command will create a `.git/config` with `svn-remote "svn"` section which you can adjust for your needs.